# 生きててすみません I can not get the sense of this

Tags: expressions

Pardon me for living? Means what? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it literally means "I'm sorry I am alive", "I apologize for surviving", or something similar. It's an expression of self-hatred. As you can probably imagine, someone who is severely depressed may say this seriously.

In addition, it's often used fairly casually/jokingly/slangily to express one's sense of embarrassment or inferiority. On SNS, you will mainly find this usage, and people usually don't take this expression too literally. You may regard this as a recurring joke. For example:

> パーティーはイケメンだらけで、生きててすみませんってなったｗ
>   there were so many good-looking guys at the party. i thought "i'm sorry i am alive" lol

Comment: Could it be like [Pardon me for living!](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pardon+me+for+living!) which has a different meaning?

Comment: @user3169 I didn't know this English expression, but 生きててすみません is not an angry expression. If people want to say sorry sarcastically when they are actually irritated, "はいはい悪かったですね" or "そりゃ悪うござんしたね" is used.

Comment: In Japanese, it's not usually used in that Western sarcastic sense, "Well, pardon me for living" (and by living, forcing you to deal with my existence) As naruto said, in Japanese the sense is usually either a serious, depressed apology, or a joke about not deserving to be alive.

Comment: I need to search this site for "sarcasm in Japanese" now ^_^